# Speed up VBA marco

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that does work, it's just really slow when there is a lot of data and I'm hoping that someone on here can help me to speed it up.

When my VBA does is check the columns of a sheet for the value "NULL" and if it's there it clears that cell. Here's the code:

```
Sub RemoveNullColumn()
    Dim c, count, r, lc, FirstCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    count = 0
    r = ActiveCell.row      'lets you choose where you want to start even if it is not at "A1"
    c = ActiveCell.Column   'lets you choose where you want to start even if it is not at "A1"
    c = GetLetterFromNumber(c)  'Gets the column letter from the number provided above
    FirstCell = c & r       'sets the cell that you selected to start in so that you will end thereafter removing all the NULL

    lc = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column   'Finding the last used column
    For H = ActiveCell.Column To lc Step 1      'Starts with where you selected a cell and moves right to the last column
        For x = 1 To Range(c & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row Step 1     'Starts with the first row and moves through the last row
            count = count + 1
            If Range(c & x).Value = "NULL" Then 'Checks the contents fo the cell to see if it is "NULL"
                Range(c & x).Clear
            End If
            If count = 1000 Then    'This was used testing but is not seen with the ScreenUpdating set to false
                Range(c & x).Select
                count = 1
            End If
        Next x
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select  'select the next column
        c = ActiveCell.Column
        c = GetLetterFromNumber(c)      'get the letter of the next column
    Next H
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Finished"
    Range(FirstCell).Select
End Sub

Function GetLetterFromNumber(Number)
    GetLetterFromNumber = Split(Cells(1, Number).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
End Function
```

When there are not a lot of rows it is pretty fast, but there are a lot of rows it is slow.

I have a file that I ran it on that has columns from A to AD and 61k+ rows, it took more than 30 minutes to finish and I'm hoping to make that much faster.

Comment: Stop using `Select`, use `With ... End With`, declare data types for your variables.

Comment: Using `count` is unnecessary.  You already have `x` counting the rows.  Also, why bother converting to column letter?  Column numbers work and you are not feeding this information back to the user.

Comment: Start your code with `Application.Calculation = xlManual` and end it with `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic`.

Comment: Too many calls to `Range()` You can declare a single range variable and set it once, and then use `.Cells(i,j)` in a `With` block to iterate over it. Even better -- find a way to avoid cell by cell iteration (e.g. by using `.Find`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of looking into Every single cell in the worksheet, use Replace function which is far faster :(you may need to edit it customize it to your needs)

Example :

```
Sub RemoveNullColumn()

  Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
  Set targetSheet = ActiveSheet 'TODO: replace with a stronger object reference

  targetSheet.Cells.Replace What:="NULL", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
   ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

This will make sure you will preserve the format.

Comment: Would this find just those cells where the only thing in them is "NULL" or will it find every instance of "NULL" even if it is part of a sentence or something else in the cells?

Comment: The LookAt:=xlWhole will require that the entire cell value is equal to the  What:="NULL".  If you want to replace within text, then use xlPart in the LookAt.

Comment: At least, take a `Range` parameter and use that instead of implicitly working against the `ActiveSheet` (through `Cells`) and thus forcing the caller to `Activate` a worksheet. As it stands, this procedure encourages callers to use the worst coding practices.

Comment: fwiw, replacing `""` with `vbNullString` is slightly faster.

Comment: To be fair, OP's macro is probably invoked from the `ActiveSheet` - I've edited the code accordingly and revoked my downvote.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes, my macro is only invoked from the `Activesheet`. I used this as the basis for my new macro and then also added several of the suggestions here like using a selection of cells instead of the whole sheet.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks! that is great info. I'll be using it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear `NULL` using ActiveCell as reference:

```
Range(ActiveCell, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Replace What:="NULL", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try...

```
Sub RemoveNullColumn()
Dim lr As Long, lc As Long
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, FirstCell As Range

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

lr = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
lc = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

Set FirstCell = ActiveCell
Set rng = Range(Cells(1, FirstCell.Column), Cells(lr, lc))

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = "NULL" Then
        cell.Clear
    End If
Next cell

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
MsgBox "Finished"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a .Find/.FindNext to collect all of the matching cells into a Union then clear the contents of the Union'ed cells.

```
Option Explicit

Sub noNULLs()
    Dim firstAddress As String, c As Range, rALL As Range
    With ActiveSheet.Cells    'This should be named worksheet like Worksheets("sheet1")
        Set c = .Find("NULL", MatchCase:=True, _
                      LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            Set rALL = c
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                Set rALL = Union(rALL, c)
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress
            rALL.Clear
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you only wanted to clear the values and not strip any formatting then change .Clear to .ClearContents.

Comment: I think your loop condition should be like this: Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress

Comment: @sktneer - c is always something because we are not clearing inside the loop. If it makes into the loop c is something and the contents of the union are not cleared until the original address is arrived at so `Not c Is Nothing` is meaningless.

Comment: Makes sense. I tested your code and it errors out at the line With ActiveSheet. It should be With ActiveSheet.Cells and also why did you use the line Worksheets(4).Range(c.Address).Activate?

Comment: @sktneer - Thanks for catching those. It was a rewrite of an older answer of mine and I neglected to run through it.

Comment: I tested both this and the excepted answer for speed b/c im a nerd & was bored - the accepted answer was faster. However as Mat'sMug pointed out, it has some bad coding practices in it. The speed difference was minimal anyway.